# Has anyone had problems registering a SECOND app with Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

I've registered one app on Google App Engine, and it works fine.  I want to register a second app now (on the same account), and every time I click the "Create an Application" button, I get forwarded to the SMS account verification page.  My number's already been used to register my first app, so of course it doesn't work.  Has anyone else seen this?  I'm using Google Apps on my domain, that seems likely to matter here.

Oh, and I've seen a number of "workarounds" for this issue - wife's cell number, prepaid cell from Wal-Mart, that sort of thing.  I'm hoping for something a little more sustainable (for my third app, etc.)

Thanks!

Comment: I didn't think the SMS was still required for additional apps.  I added apps 3 and 4 without providing a cell number.

Comment: Yup, it shouldn't be.  But I'm still getting the account confirmation page.  Are you using GAE on your own domain?  For example, do you have to go to "https://appengine.google.com/a/yourdomain.com/" instead of "https://appengine.google.com/"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that this has happened to others. It seems that the app engine team sometimes has to address these manually. Try filling this form out...

https://appengine.google.com/waitlist/sms_issues

Comment: Filled out this form, and 24 hours later they sent me a mail saying the problem was fixed (and it appears to be).  Glad to see they're responsive to their "customers" (even the ones who don't pay them).  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create 10 apps per account, but you can only have one account linked to each phone number.

Comment: I agree that I should, and everything claims that I can.  Unfortunately, trying to add another app takes me directly to the SMS confirmation page again (which in turn, claims that I won't have to do this twice).